# Jquery .post and Codeigniter issue

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am trying to use $.post to send the data to Controller and receive the returned data. I use project_detail/pub as my designated url and want to return `$go` from the controller. However, The returned data is a html page which is from 'show' function not 'pub' function. I have no idea what's going on. Please help. Thanks a lot.

view page: Jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#update').click(function(){
    var tableVal=new Array();
        //get the value from table td       
        $('#projects tr td').each(function (){
            tableVal[this.id] = $(this).text();
        });

        //send data to the controller 'project_detail' and function 'pub' with .post    
        $.post('project_detail/pub', {'tableVal':tableVal},function(result)
        {
            alert(result);
        })
    })
});
```

Controller code

```
class Project_detail extends CI_Controller{

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    //The url I send to with .post and want to return $go 
    public function pub()
    {
    $go='test! test!';
    return $go;
    }

    //for some reasons, `$this->load->view('include/template', $data)` is loaded to the     
    //result in view page instead of $go
    public function show () 
    {                   
        $data['view']='project_detail_V';
        $this->load->view('include/template', $data);

    }


}
```

Comment: Have you tried A) viewing the project_detail/pub page in the web browser, or B) trying the same jQuery script with a simple get to see if you can get your result?   Also, I normally would echo $go instead of returning $go, but maybe both will work--never tried just returning like that.

Comment: I got it. It seems that I need to add base_url() in my .post like followiing: $.post('<?=base_url()?>/project_detail/pub', {'tableVal':tableVal},function(go)
   {
    alert(go);
   })

Answer (score 0):

You aren't outputting the value anywhere. Try this instead.

```
//The url I send to with .post and want to return $go 
public function pub()
{
   $go='test! test!';
   print $go;
}
```

You can also use firebug or similar inspectors to see what values you get back from CI during the request.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

## javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#update').click(function(){
    var tableVal=new Array();
        //get the value from table td       
        $('#projects tr td').each(function (){
            tableVal[this.id] = $(this).text();
        });

        //send data to the controller 'project_detail' and function 'pub' with .post    
        $.post('project_detail/pub', {'tableVal':tableVal},function(result)
        {
            alert(result);
        },'json');
    })
});
```

## controller

```
public function pub()
{
   $go='test! test!';

   echo json_encode($go);
}
```